# Create a variable whose shape is only determined at run time

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to create the inputs to an RNN cell which has takes

1. An input tensor `x` of dimensions `batch_size x time_step x n_classes`
2. An initial hidden state tensor `h` of dimensions `batch_size x hidden_state_size`

The problem now is that I am unsure how to use `tf.get_variable(...)` to create `h` such that it has a shape of `? x hidden_state_size` where `?` is the current batch size.

I don't have this problem with `x` as I am able to define `x` like so:

```
x = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.pretrained_embeddings, self.input_placeholder)
x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, self.max_length, Config.n_features * Config.embed_size))
```

So the `batch_size` is automatically inferred from `tf.reshape`

So `x.get_shape()` would give me `(?, max_length, n_features * embed_size)`

The only workaround I have to create `h` is the following:

```
 # x_ is of shape (max_length, batch_size, n_features * embed_size)
 x_ = tf.unstack(x, axis = 1) 

 # h is of shape (batch_size, n_features)
 h = tf.get_variable("h", tf.shape(x_[0]), initializer = 
 tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
```

Then `h.get_shape()` would give the desired `(?, n_features * embed_size)` which by chance is equal to my `hidden_state_size`. The problem with this workaround is that this only works if the `hidden_state_size` is equal to `n_features * embed_size` which may not always be the case.

Is there a way such that I can define the hidden tensor `h` so that it can have a shape of `(?, hidden_state_size)` without the error:

> ValueError: Shape of a new variable (pred/h) must be fully defined,
>   but instead was (?, 300)

Answer (score 0):

Silly me I could have just done something like:

`h = tf.zeros(shape = (tf.shape(x)[0], n_features * embed_size))`